# Python objects.all command not registering?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to make a for loop that prints out every user in my database to my website page... the only problem is that the attribute "objects" refuses to register and I do not understand the problem...

```
def index(request):
    all_users = UserInfo.objects.all()
    context = {'all_users':index}
    for user in all_users:
        url = '/index/' + str(user.id) + '/'
        # html = '<a href="' + url + '">' + all_users + '</a><br>'
    return render(request, 'userData/allUsers.html', context)
```

That is my code, and the error is "Unresolved attribute reference 'objects'".

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = "User:" + str(first_name) + " " + str(last_name) + "."
    SERVER_ROLE = (
        ('creator', 'CREATOR'),
        ('admin', 'ADMIN'),
        ('moderator', 'MODERATOR'),
        ('normie', 'NORMIE'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SERVER_ROLE, default='normie')
```

This is the class that "UserInfo" relates to; if you need any more of my code I can add it to the question.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/enzoromano/DiscordSite/DiscordBot/userData/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import UserInfo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Comment: Can you provide error stack trace?

Comment: I edited my question. Seems like a completely different problem that might be the cause of it... Sorry I am still a new python coder

Comment: How do you start your application?

Comment: What is going on this line ? context = {'all_users':index}

Comment: shouldn't it be context = {'all_users':all_users}

Comment: @donnyyy When I use python manage.py runserver, I get no errors, but when I run it in my IDE which is PyCharm, I get the error

Comment: @OjasKale yes you were right. Im sorry I am really new to this, even after fixing that line though I still get the "ModuleNotFoundError" when i try to import .models

Comment: You should start the server by ``python manage.py runserver``, not by PyCharm so it could load your modules, not just a file

Comment: You can't execute a django views (or models or whatever) module like it was a script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
context = {'all_users':index}
```

to

```
{'all_users':all_users}
```

Comment: Changing import package name won't solve unloaded module

Comment: Lol another problem arose with my query set, but hey at least it prints out now. Thank you both so much

Comment: @EnzoRomano if you could not get that thing working, pass it over to community. :)

Comment: @OjasKale its basically just printing out my query set as ....
<QuerySet [<UserInfo: Andrew>, <UserInfo: Jon>, <UserInfo: enzoromano>]>

Comment: are you trying to print it in html template or to console from view  ?

Comment: {% for users in all_users %}
     <p>{{ all_users }}</p>{% endfor %}

Comment: ohhh right. first instead of {{all_users}} it should be {{users}} (you  might want to change it to 'user' for sake of correctness)

Comment: also, define a __str__() (or __unicode__())method in UserInfo class that way it would print user info the way you want.

def __unicode__(self): return  self.first_name + ' '+ self.last_name

Comment: or instead of defining a __unicode__ method you can write this in template itself. {{ user.first_name + user.last_name }}. but writing __unicode__ is a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in previous questions, replace

```
context = {'all_users':index}
```

to

```
{'all_users':all_users}
```

And start your server with `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Thank you so much!